# PDO and mysqli simultaneously - Risk of collision?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo

We are using [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) as our master database connection and are thinking of moving to using [Doctrine DBAL](https://github.com/doctrine/dbal) which is an abstraction over [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). PDO itself is a database abstraction layer which offers us more flexibility.

The plan is to actually use these in parallel when refactoring code, slowly migrating our current queries to use DBAL.

I have heard some concerns from some of my colleagues that two database connectors, one using mysqli and one PDO, have the risk of colliding, causing possible lock situations etc. But aren't these possible in a scenario where we only have mysqli but multiple processes running? Is this really an issue?

Comment: we haven't had any issues, and we use both

Comment: _But aren't these possible in a scenario where we only have mysqli but multiple processes running?_  Yes, exactly, shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: IMHO too much troubles you just can't foresee. I would fake mysqli using a PDO wrapper.

Comment: Collision might happen even if you just use PDO / MySQLi, if there are a lot of concurrent connections and locking occurs. Chances are minimal unless you intentionally lock up tables / rows, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use mysqli and PDO in the same script. Just like you can create multiple connections to the same database even if you only use one of these connectors.

You always have the risk of concurrent connections having lock contention. But this is no more risky by using multiple connectors.

Comment: Oh sure one can, *but*... you just can't *mix* them together.

Comment: Right, like you can't make a query on one connection and fetch the results on the other connection. But you can't do that anyway, whether you use different connectors or if they're both mysqli or both PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Well this proved to be correct, but a problems occur elsewhere. Two separate connections are not privy to each others transactions. When you begin a transaction with DBAL and insert rows with mysqli, you cannot rollback insertions with DBAL. This creates a problem and the solution becomes unusable.